# How to show and access SAGA not shown in Processing Panel in QGIS 2.18.4?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga, tools, qgis-2.18

How to get SAGA modules to show and be usable within QGIS, i.e. from within the Processing Panel?

I have tried reinstalling SAGA (now = Version: 2.1.2 64 bit) through the OSGEO4w installer and tried reconfiguring the "SAGA Folder" but to no avail.
(i.e. as per http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html?highlight=saga#saga)

I am not sure when or why SAGA stopped displaying in the Processing Panel, but I had used SAGA from this location not too long ago.

I note also that the standalone version of SAGA (Version: 2.1.2 64 bit) now reinstalled works, but can not find how to access though QGIS via either the processing toolbox or graphical modeller etc.

Using QGIS 2.18.4 on Win7_64

[image: Oh where did thou go dear SAGA?]

Comment: If I change the SAGA folder, QGIS complains about missing MSYS folder, but after restarting QGIS I have the SAGA modules. can you try renaming the `.qgis2` folder, and restart QGIS? BTW QGIS from OSGEO4W64 does not ask for the folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AndreJ. I have since restarted QGIS again and PC and ....... SAGA is back and seems to be working!!! I didn't get to renaming the .qgis folder as suggested to test this method. Will remember for next time ... but what would I rename it to/ would it affect other things that use it? (on the BTW ... where do you mean it does not ask for the folder, in the dialog in the picture above or elsewhere as I only have OSGEO4W installs on PC and it is still in the Processing>options dialog?).

Comment: The `.qgis2` folder contains user settings, and will be recreated if it gets destroyed or renamed to whatever. Windows would not let you rename it back, because it does not let you enter folder names starting with a period.