# Raster data like heatmap from polygons w.r.t their own values

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, smoothing, fill

I have polygons as below, and each polygon is assigned to some value.
What I'd like to do are ...

- Smoothen boundaries (Values should change more smoothly around boundaries)
- Fill N/A part properly
- Generate raster data which met the above

How can I get such a raster data with QGIS ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this example gives you an idea; you can play with the workflow according to your plan how to smooth and/or how you want to fill the N/A area.

In this one **Simple filter** was used to smooth, and **Close Gaps with spline** was used to fill the N/A hole.

Input polygon:

[image]

Output raster:

[image]

Workflow:

1. Create a polygon layer (your_polygon.shp), and assign Value field. Give zero to the N/A polygon. (*See Input polygon*)
2. Rasterize the polygon layer (your_polygon.shp) and save it as (your_raster.tif)
3. Reclassify the raster value 0 to nodata. `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Raster Tools | Reclassify values` 
   `Method [0] single, old value= 0.0, new value= -99999`. 
   Tick off `replace no data values` and `replace other values`.
   It will give you (Reclassified Grid) layer.
4. Smooth the (Reclassified Grid) raster layer. `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Raster filter | Simple filter`
   Radius should be given by pixels
   It will give you (Filtered Grid) raster layer.
5. Run `Close Gaps with spline` without mask on the (Filtered Grid) raster layer .
   `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Raster Tools | Close Gaps with spline`
   This will give you (Closed Gaps Grid) raster layer (nodata value is not filled yet).
6. Save this raster layer as mask.tif for later use. (This is actually used as a dummy file but it ensures the raster extent of mask be the same with the target layer).
7. Dissolve the polygon layer (your_polygon.shp) to make a mask (mask.shp)
   Rasterize the mask polygon (mask.shp) onto the mask.tif
8. Again, `Close Gaps with spline` on the (Filtered Grid) with mask (mask.tif) and it is done. (*See Output raster*)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to follow the instructions, but I don't have SAGA Raster filter. I enabled SAGA at Processing -> Options, but SAGA doesn't appear(I restarted QGIS, but it didn't work.) I'm using QGIS 2.18.5, should it be out of box ?

Comment: It should be. As far as I could find most recent case was reported on [2.18.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231035/how-to-show-and-access-saga-not-shown-in-processing-panel-in-qgis-2-18-4) and it was fixed by restarting QGIS and PC, as you have done already. Can you post your case as new question?